# Почему в условии не банится ноль?

Tags: c#

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace game
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string user1, user2, winner;
            Console.Write("Введите ник 1 игрока - ");
            user1 = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Введите ник 2 игрока - ");
            user2 = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Можно вводить числа от 1 до 4");
            Random rand = new Random();
            int number = rand.Next(12, 40);
            int move;
            winner = "пососал";
            while (number>0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Число: {number}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Ход: {user1}");

                    move = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                if (move > 0 && move < 5 && move != 0)
                    {
                        number = number-move;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        while (move < 0 || move > 4)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Неверный диапазон чисел (1,2,3 и 4)");
                            move = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                        }
                        number = number - move;
                    }
                    if (number==0)
                    {
                        winner = user1;
                    }

                Console.WriteLine($"Число: {number}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Ход: {user2}");
                move = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                if (move > 0 && move < 5 && move != 0)
                {
                    number = number - move;
                }
                else
                {
                    while (move < 0 || move > 4)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Неверный диапазон чисел (1,2,3 и 4)");
                        move = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    }
                    number = number - move;
                }
                if (number == 0)
                {
                    winner = user2;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"Победил {winner}" );

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А в чём смысл проверки `move != 0`, если уже определили что `move > 0 && move < 5`?

Comment: Я пробовал просто `move > 0 && move < 5`, не работает. Я решил ещё раз написать тоже самое по другому, но оно всё равно не хочет работать.

Comment: Возможно в `while` должно быть `move < 1 || move > 4` вместо `move < 0 || move > 4`?

Comment: @EOF Спасибо, работает)

Comment: Кто-нибудь введёт букву и код `int.Parse` выбросит исключение.

Answer (score 1):

У Вас в циклах `while` условие `move < 0 || move > 4`. При `move == 0` результатом условия будет `false` и цикл обработки ошибок завершится. Измените условие на `move < 1 || move > 4`. Также проверка `move != 0` в `if`'ах не нужна.